# Convert uint16_t integer to UTF-8 string stored in uint8_t array

Tags: c++, utf-8, arduino

I'm working on a project involving an Arduino that's reading sensor data and transmitting it to an app via a BLE connection.  The sensor library I'm using returns a uint16_t integer value and the BLE library is expecting a uint8_t[20] as a buffer.  The App on the receiving end is interpreting the data as UTF-8 bytes.  So I need to convert a uint16_t integer into a UTF-8 string and store it in an array.

I haven't used C++ in 15 years so this is the best I've managed to come up with but it fails in a number of ways.

```
// global vars for transmit buffer
static uint8_t transmit_buffer[20];
static uint8_t transmit_buffer_size;

// read sensor data using vendor lib
uint16_t mm = sensor.read();

char buf[6];

transmit_buffer_size = sprintf(buf, "%d", mm);

// copy data buffer to transmit buffer
for(uint8_t i = 0; i < transmit_buffer_size; i++)
    transmit_buffer[i] = buf[i];

// transmit data
transmitter.send(transmit_buffer, transmit_buffer_size);

// zero out the transmit buffer after use
memset(transmit_buffer, 0x00, 20);
```

What's a better way of doing this?

Comment: You should be aware of endianess issues.

Comment: Its the same as converting it into an `ASCII` string because `UTF-8` codes coincide with `ASCII` for numeric digits.

Comment: Menset are unnecesary, cause you are settings values later

Comment: @Galik - I know that UTF-8 is backward compatible with ASCII, I just wasn't sure if this is the best way to go about converting.  I haven't used C++ since University and I'm a little rusty.

Comment: @MyItchyChin What you are doing looks fine to me. I don't know much about Arduino and whether or not it comes with restricted libraries? Otherwise I suspect people might use `std::to_string()` to convert the number and then copy the string into a correctly typed buffer (`std::array<20, uint8_t> buf{};`?) for transmission `transmitter.send(buf.data(), buf.size())`.